# Picture Box out of Memory

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing a windows form application. At one of my form i place a picture box control. 
Its working fine for majority of time. But sometime it displays red cross rather than displaying actual picture.

I further explore this and came to know that this control handle exceptions internally. So i go to `Debug->Exceptions` and Check the relevant `thrown` boxes. Then i found that the red box is display due to following error:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll

Additional information: Out of memory.
```

Could any body suggest me how to deal with this exception?

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449587/out-of-memory-with-multi-images-in-one-picturebox

Comment: Are you resusing the picturebox for multiple images? If so, are you disposing the previous image before you load the next one?

Comment: Check that your not stuck in an endless loop somewhere. Check that the size of the picture is not like 1gb or something. Check that your computer is not just really old and out of memory.

Comment: You might have to add some code for someone to give you a solid answer.

Comment: @Jason Down: Exactly i am using this for multiple images. Please tell me how to dispose previous image?

Comment: @Jame: when Merlyn says, "add some code", he means "show some code"

Comment: @Jame the answer to disposing images is posted in the first comment by Waqas

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As pair to you comment that you are using multiple images in the `PictureBox`, you should "like @Jason suggested" `Dispose()` the old image before applying the new one, like:

```
private void ChangePictureBoxImage(Image image)
{
    pictureBox.Image.Dispose(); // dispose the old image.
    pictureBox.Image = image;
}
```

Comment: Saved my day :) Thank you.

Comment: For me, this did not work unfortunately... I could not see anything in the pictureb-box. the solution for me was to just save the current image to a variable, set the new one and than dispose the saved one.

Comment: if( pictureBox.Image != null) was necessary for me, seems to not be set initially.

Answer (score 0):

How much RAM does your target machine have?

You got this exception because the call to allocate more memory for the image failed. If you are unable to increase the amount of memory on your computer, try reducing the image's size or close any other programs you have running.

Comment: Does anybody really think that there's even a remote possibility that he's out of RAM/Virtual memory?

Comment: That's what the exception means...as you can see in the accepted answer above, he was indeed running out of memory.

Comment: It has nothing to do with RAM. This error is thrown when there is not enough memory in the current address bus - which is a completely different concept.