# System.OutOfMemoryException: 'Out of memory.'

Tags: c#, video, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

update

I am using videoSourcePlayer from AForge. now I had to add a function to it because 
`GetCurrentVideoFrame( )` was not working the way I needed. So I make a function called  `GetCurrent()` and it works the way I wanted.  The problem I am having is when I used it in place of `GetCurrentVideoFrame( )` I get a System.OutOfMemoryException: 'Out of memory.' Exception and I have no Ideal why.
here is my code :

```
Bitmap getPic2(int i2)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = null;
        Bitmap tempB = null;
        if (endIRList[i2].X > videoSourcePlayer.Width - 1)
            endIRList[i2]= new System.Drawing.Point(videoSourcePlayer.Width - 1, endIRList[i2].Y);
        if (endIRList[i2].Y > videoSourcePlayer.Height - 1)
            endIRList[i2] = new System.Drawing.Point(endIRList[i2].X, videoSourcePlayer.Height - 1);
        if (stIRList[i2].X >= 0 && stIRList[i2].Y >= 0 && endIRList[i2].X < videoSourcePlayer.Width && endIRList[i2].Y < videoSourcePlayer.Height)
        {
            if (endIRList[i2].X - stIRList[i2].X > 0 && endIRList[i2].Y - stIRList[i2].Y > 0)
            {
                bmp = videoSourcePlayer.GetCurrent();
                System.Drawing.Image iOld = p2.Image;
                tempB = bmp.Clone(new Rectangle(stIRList[i2].X, stIRList[i2].Y, endIRList[i2].X - stIRList[i2].X, endIRList[i2].Y - stIRList[i2].Y),bmp.PixelFormat);

                if (iOld != null)
                {
                    iOld.Dispose();
                    iOld = null;
                }
            }
        }
        pictureBox1.Image =this.videoSourcePlayer.GetCurrent();

        TestPicBox.Image = tempB;


        return tempB;
    }
```

the problem I am having is at:

```
tempB = bmp.Clone(new Rectangle(stIRList[i2].X, stIRList[i2].Y, endIRList[i2].X - stIRList[i2].X, endIRList[i2].Y - stIRList[i2].Y),bmp.PixelFormat);
```

now if I just use `bmp = GetCurrentVideoFrame` I do not get the problem. so something must is wrong with my function   `GetCurrentVideo`

here is the code :

```
  public Bitmap GetCurrentVideoFrame( )
    {
        lock ( sync )
        {
            return ( currentFrame == null ) ? null : AForge.Imaging.Image.Clone( currentFrame );
        }
    }

      public Bitmap GetCurrent()
    {
        lock (sync)
        {
            Bitmap currentPic = null;
            Bitmap original = GetCurrentVideoFrame();
            currentPic = new Bitmap(original, new Size(original.Width / 2, original.Height / 2));
            original.Dispose();
            original = null;
            return currentPic;

        }

    }
```

I just cant see why their function works and my does not.
can anyone help?

Comment: Similar thread can be found here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199468/c-sharp-image-clone-out-of-memory-exception You have to use proper clean up and disposing methods.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Picture Box out of Memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991157/picture-box-out-of-memory)

Answer (score 4):

In short, your program is one large efficient unmanaged GDI memory leak

If a bitmap gets created or cloned, you need to dispose it at some stage (using the `Dispose` method). This, you are not doing

Both `tempB` (seriously bad naming by the way) and `bmp` need to be disposed at some point.

You can't wish them away, or ignore them.

***Tip**, if you play with a bitmap, or unmanaged resource, pay special attention to when and where it gets used, and make sure it's disposed of properly*.

Comment: ok I am not sure where to add it at ,  original has one. and I am returning currentPic so I can do that one. and it deads before i am done using bmp.

Comment: @brandon What is the size of the rectangle you are trying to create? if that is overly large you will have the same issue

Comment: I make it dynamically but when I use their function GetCurrentVideoFrame( ) I never get that error. no matter how big or small the rectangle is

Comment: Does the contents of `pictureBox1.Image` need to be disposed as well?

Comment: but that is after where is dead at

Comment: @brandon so this code is never called more than once, and dies the firs time?

Comment: @brandon So it runs more than once?, or just once

Comment: no only one time. I press a button and it call it and it dead

Comment: @brandon What line exactly

Comment: tempB = bmp.Clone(new Rectangle(stIRList[i2].X, stIRList[i2].Y, endIRList[i2].X - stIRList[i2].X, endIRList[i2].Y - stIRList[i2].Y),bmp.PixelFormat);

Comment: @brandon What are the exact measurements of this rectangle dimensions, when it breaks

Comment: @brandon that perfectly dodged the question, you need to give me the measurements of at least one time it breaks

Comment: start point X = 135, starting point Y = 294, end point X=  165,  end point Y = 327

Comment: @ theGeneral does that help ?

Comment: anyone has any ideas ?