# Out of memory error when trying to open a Dicom image in a picture box, which is opened in a seperate form

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a Windows form software which at a button click is supposed to open a file dialogue and after selecting the Dicom image file it is supposed ot open another form that contains the Dicom image in a picture box.

The problem is that whenever I try to test it, I get a `System.OutOfMemoryException: 'Out of memory.'` error which appears at `pictureBox.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(refImagePath1);`.

```
private void run_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string inputFolderPath = SrcTextBox.Text;
    string outputFolderPath = DstTextBox.Text;

    // Get a list of all DICOM files in the input folder
    string[] dicomFiles = Directory.GetFiles(inputFolderPath, "*.dcm");

    // Check if there are any DICOM files in the folder
    if (dicomFiles.Length > 0)
    {
        int i = 0;

        // Create a list to store DICOM information for each file
        List<string> dicomInfoList = new List<string>();

        // Prompt user to select the first reference DICOM file
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "DICOM Files|*.dcm";
        openFileDialog1.Title = "Select First Reference DICOM File";

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string refFilename1 = Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            string refPath1 = Path.GetDirectoryName(openFileDialog1.FileName);

            // Load the reference DICOM image
            string refImagePath1 = Path.Combine(refPath1, refFilename1);
            string refInfo1 = refImagePath1;           

            PictureBox pictureBox = new PictureBox();
            pictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
            pictureBox.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(refImagePath1); //This is the problem.

            // Create a new form
            Form form = new Form();
            form.Size = new Size(800, 600);
            form.Controls.Add(pictureBox);
            form.BackgroundImage = pictureBox.Image;

            form.ShowDialog();

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No reference file selected. Exiting.");
            return;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No DICOM files found in the selected directory.");
    }
}
```

Previous test were succesful in generating the form but not the dicom image.

Comment: Does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991157/picture-box-out-of-memory?rq=2) help you?

Comment: Please follow this site's tagging guidelines by NOT putting tags in your question title. `[C#] [WinForms]` are not needed there, since the site already has a perfectly adequate tagging system (which you've used).

Comment: Read the 'Exception' part here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.fromfile?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0

Comment: That image format is not supported -- The path construction is overly complicated for no reason

Comment: DICOM is not a standard picture format that can be handled by the builtin function. You need a [specialized library](https://github.com/fo-dicom/fo-dicom). Note that dicom images are also *typically* 16bit grayscale, so you typically need some way to "window level" the image. The DICOM spec is also huge, with all kinds of different ways to store images. So you will likely have quite a bit of work to do, depending on your ambition level.