# PictureBox OutOfMemory

Tags: c#, .net, picturebox

I'm currently programming a Program which displays all pictures of a folder after another, but although I use dispose before I load the new Image, I get the OutOfMemory exception after a few picture. My Task Manager shows nearly constant RAM usage so there shouldn't be a Memory Leak...

```
private void loadImage()
{
    if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
    }
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(filenames[index]);
}
```

Comment: Your code to dispose looks fine. Pretty sure it's the last line causing the issue when it encounters something it can't load. See the accepted answer here for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449587/out-of-memory-with-multi-images-in-one-picturebox

Comment: Always the same file that throws? How large are the files?

Comment: If you check your taskmanager on handles. will it increase? I think about file handles getting lost.

Comment: Do you call load images one by one within a timer tick or in a click event handler or do you load them all together from the same event ?

Comment: I tried the exact same thing in Visual Studio 2013 instead of VS 2012 and there it works, but in VS2012 i always get this exception. Maybe a bug in my .net version?

@Graffito i load them within a click event handler.

Comment: Most certainly not a bug in .Net. Any reason why you didn't answer our questions? What are the numbers and the sizes of the files involved?